# Работа с формами

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть несколько идущих подряд форм

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>

<form>
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="2">
<input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Используя ajax и jquery отправляется POST запрос, передающий всего 1 значение из скрытого поля i, вопрос в том как выбрать это значение в зависимости от формы в которой кликнули по кнопке ок. Или, что, еще интереснее как сделать тоже самое, только без формы, например, кликая по ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form class="add"> 
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="1"> 
<input type="submit" value="ok"> 
</form>

<form class="add"> 
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="2"> 
<input type="submit" value="ok"> 
</form>

$(function() {  
    $("form.add").submit(function(){ 
        $.post("test.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data){ 
        }); 
        return false; 
    });  
});
```

К каждой форме всего лишь необходимо было добавить класс.

Comment: Ваше решение не решает задачи, которую Вы перед собой поставили. Используя Ваш код, на сервер отправятся данные из всех форм, имеющих класс add. Смотрите выше решение - я уже исправил

Comment: Ну как то не решает? Вы внимательно прочтите первое предложение.
Что касается варианта с ссылками, гордить огород из кучи id под каждую ссылку поле формы - неочень. Для всех ссылок можно использовать один id, а в саму ссылку писать дополнительный параметр с значением и его передавать, очень красивое и просто решение.

Comment: это тоже вариант, но по поводу кучи id поспорю - ваш способ ничем не лучше - Вы создаете кучу форм, а это еще хуже.

Answer (score 3):

вешай обработчик на клик по ссылке, в котором отправляешь запрос, а именно значение только одного поля. Ответ кроется в самом вопросе.
Можно поступить следующим образом: давать имена скрытым полям почти такие же как и ссылкам с единственной лишь разницей - в начале прибавим букву h. Затем после щелчка по ссылке определим имя нажатой ссылки и сформируем программным образом имя соответствующего скрытого поля.
Код отправки примерно такой :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#error').hide();
var hiddenname='';
$("#container").click(function (e) {
if (e.target.id!='') {hiddenname = e.target.id; hiddenname='h'+hiddenname;}

 var x = $(hiddenname).val();//получаем в переменную х значение из скрытого поля

 $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: "x="+x,
    success: function(html){
    $("#error").append(html);
    $("#error").slideDown('slow');
                }           
});
});
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="error"></div>
    <div id="container">
<form>
 <a href="#" id="link1">link1</a>
<input type=hidden id="hlink1"><br><br>
 <a href="#" id="link2">link2</a>
<input type=hidden id="hlink2"><br><br>
 <a href="#" id="link3">link3</a>
<input type=hidden id="hlink3"><br><br>
 <a href="#" id="link4">link4</a>
<input type=hidden id="hlink4"><br><br>
</form>
</div>
```

А затем на сервере вынимаешь значение переменной **х** из POST-массива

Comment: Такой вариант работает только для первой формы, все остальные не реагируют на клик, такой вариант неочень.

Comment: еще раз - у вас есть несколько ссылок. За каждой из них закреплено скрытое поле. В зависимости от того на какую ссылку кликнули, нужно отправить соответствующее поле. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Всё верно.